# dd div shows correct margin in Chrome, but is broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have an FAQ page with questions:
http://www.simplypsychics.com/booking.html

The positioning of the question is correct (acceptable is probably a better word) in Chrome, but when I look at it in Firefox, it's floating too much to the right:
[image]

Does anyone know what piece of code I need to change?
I tried padding and margin but it messes it up in Chrome.

I also tried adding stuff to 'Element' tag but no joy except in Firebug!

Hope someone can help.

This is the HTML code I use:

```
<div class="headerstandard">Important Information before you begin your application!</div>
<div id="faq">                               
<div id="faqSection">
<dl>        
<dt>How do I apply to join SimplyPsychics.com?</dt>
<dd>To join our team, you must complete an online application. Unfortunately we don't send application forms in the post.</dd>
</dl>
</div></div></div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#faq{
width:100%;
background-color: #fcf6ff;
border-radius: 5px;

}

#faqSection{
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white;
}

.headerstandard{
color:#9a3ba8;
font-size:22px;
margin-top:14px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid transparent;
}   
dt{
color:#8F9AA3;
font-size:18px;
padding: 10px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid transparent;
}

dt:hover{ color:#9a3ba8;}

dt.opened { background-position:left bottom;}

dd{
font-size:14px;
color:#717f89;
line-height:1.5;
padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
width:95%;
display:none;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are still quite new to SO (so first of all: Welcome!). When asking a question, please keep in mind that we are not really interested in opinions and remarks, which are not relevant to the question. If your question is more to the point, you will likely get more or better answers. That is why I edited your question, if you were wondering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this but their answer got deleted! :(
I did a CSS Reset and applied this code to the header of the document, just before calling the stylesheet. It fixed it in chrome too:

```
dl, dt, dd {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a go in Firefox, and it seems the DD element has an extra margin. You can notice it using the [boxmodel view of Firefox web developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector#Box_model_view). Adding this should do it then :

```
dd {
    margin-left:0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it seems that Firefox (Gecko) is *correct* and keeps to the [default style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) defined for `dd` and adds `margin-left: 40px` style attribute.

Tested in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBk5t/) the non standard compliant behaviour is confirmed in Chrome. You can overcome this by forcing a different margin in your CSS or inline.